# C++ - How to call a templated method of a recursively inherited templated base class

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, non-type-template-parameter

I'm trying to create a `Tuple` class with an arbitrary number of entries with arbitrary types using variadic templates and the ability to get the `n`th entry with a templatized `entry` method, so I can use it as follows:

```
Tuple<int, int, std::string, double> t(1, 2, "Hello World", 3.4);
std::cout << t.entry<1>() << std::endl; // Prints 2
std::cout << t.entry<2>() << std::endl; // Prints "Hello World"
```

My current approach:

```
template<typename ...Types>
struct Tuple;

template<typename Type>
struct Tuple<Type>
{
    Tuple(Type value) : value(value) { };
    Type value;

    template<int Index>
    Type& entry()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

template<typename Type, typename... Types>
struct Tuple<Type, Types...> : public Tuple<Types...>
{
    Tuple(Type value, Types ...args) : Tuple<Types...>(args...), value(value) { }
    Type value;

    template<int Index>
    auto entry() -> decltype(Tuple<Types...>::entry<Index-1>())&
    {
        return Tuple<Types...>::entry<Index-1>();
    }

    template<>
    Type& entry<0>() 
    {
        return value;
    }
};
```

The first struct providing the "base" case for one element and the second struct building recursively upon that. However, I get the error

```
In member function ‘decltype (((Tuple<Types ...>::entry < (Index - 1)) > <expression error>))& Tuple<Type, Types ...>::entry()’:
error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
```

How can I call a templated method of a templated base class?

Comment: Where's your initial declaration of `struct Tuple`? These are both specializations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using at least C++14, you can use [`auto&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) instead of a trailing return type, and as pointed out by [max66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180700/1541563) you need to add the `template` keyword before the member function invocation in your syntax.

You can also simplify your definition because you just need an empty base class, not a class which implements a specialization for one type; your second class already implements the necessary behavior for one type. This simplification requires you to rewrite `entry()` using [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), or [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) if you're using C++17

```cpp
// only needed for C++14 when using std::enable_if
#include <type_traits>

template<typename...>
struct Tuple
{
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct Tuple<T, Ts...> : public Tuple<Ts...>
{
    Tuple(T value, Ts ...args) : value(value), Tuple<Ts...>(args...) { }
    T value;

    template<std::size_t I, std::enable_if_t<I == 0, bool> = true>
    T& entry() { return value; }

    template<std::size_t I, std::enable_if_t<I != 0, bool> = true>
    auto& entry() { return Tuple<Ts...>::template entry<I - 1>(); }

    // // requires C++17 support
    // template<std::size_t I>
    // auto& entry() {
    //     if constexpr (I == 0) { return value; }
    //     else { return Tuple<Ts...>::template entry<I - 1>(); }
    // }
};
```

Try it on [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/PzKWf4)

Answer (score 2):

You need add a `template`   before `::entry`

```
template<int Index> // ...................VVVVVVVVV
auto entry() -> decltype(Tuple<Types...>::template entry<Index-1>())&
{ // .......................VVVVVVVVV
    return Tuple<Types...>::template entry<Index-1>();
}
```

or the `<` after `::entry` is parsed as a relational operator.

But you have another problem: the specialization of `entry()`:

```
template<>
Type& entry<0>() 
{
    return value;
}
```

Unfortunately you can't specialize the a method without specializing the containing class.

If you can compile C++17, you can avoid method specialization and use `if constexpr`

```
template <int Index>
auto & entry()
 {
   if constexpr ( Index == 0 )
      return value;
   else 
      return Tuple<Types...>::template entry<Index-1>();
 }
```

<s>Pre C++17</s> In C++14... I suppose you can solve using tag dispatching

```
template <int>
Type & entry_helper (std::true_type)
 { return value; }

template <int Index>
auto & entry_helper (std::false_type)
 { return Tuple<Types...>::template entry<Index-1>(); }

template <int Index>
auto & entry()
{ return entry_helper<Index>(std::integral_constant<bool, Index==0>{}); }
```

<del>In C++11 you need also the trailing return type in for `entry()` and for the second `entry_helper()`</del>

As pointed by Patrick Roberts (thanks!) the solution, adding trailing return type, works for C++11 with g++ but not for clang++, for a problem in detecting the return type in a context of recursion.

For C++11 I propose a completely different solution that avoid the `entry()`/`entry_helper()` recursion but add another level of indirection at class level (add a recursive base class struct `Tpl`). Add also perfect forwarding, unsigned indexes and const-versions for `entry()` and `entry_helper()`.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t, typename...>
struct Tpl
 { void entry_helper () {} };

template <std::size_t I, typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct Tpl<I, T, Ts...> : public Tpl<I+1u, Ts...>
 {
   using Tpl<I+1, Ts...>::entry_helper;

   Tpl (T && t, Ts && ... ts)
      : Tpl<I+1u, Ts...>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}, value{std::forward<T>(t)}
    { }

   T value;

   T & entry_helper (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>)
    { return value; }

   T const & entry_helper (std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>) const
    { return value; }
 };

template <typename ... Ts>
struct Tuple : public Tpl<0, Ts...>
 {
   using Tpl<0, Ts...>::entry_helper;

   Tuple (Ts && ... ts) : Tpl<0u, Ts...>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...}
    { }

   template <std::size_t I>
   auto entry ()
    -> decltype(entry_helper(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})) &
    { return entry_helper(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}); }

   template <std::size_t I>
   auto entry () const
    -> decltype(entry_helper(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{})) const &
    { return entry_helper(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}); }
 };

int main()
 {
   Tuple<int, int, std::string, double> t(1, 2, "Hello World", 3.4);

   std::cout << t.entry<1>() << std::endl; // Prints 2
   std::cout << t.entry<2>() << std::endl; // Prints "Hello World"
 }
```

Comment: I went down the rabbit-hole of C++11-compatible trailing return types and no matter what I tried I only got `no matching member function for call to 'entry'` (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/1q7M5h)). I did notice that using `std::integral_constant<int, Index>` seemed like a cleaner choice for dispatching to your `entry_helper` overloads though.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Intriguing... I reproduce the error with clang++ but g++ compiles without problems... I don't understand who's right.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - to be sure, I've added a C++11 specific solution that avoid the recursion at level of methods (but add a level of indirection... less elegant that the others, C++14 and C++17, solutions).

Comment: Wow, nice job, you really should've gotten the accepted answer mark...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - Naaaa... not so nice. And also your answer deserves to be accepted.